# Customise Laravel Nova destructive action modal

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am defining a new destructive action in Laravel Nova using the [documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/actions/defining-actions.html), and I am wondering if it is possible to customise the modal message, which says "Are you sure you want to run this action".

So far, all I have been able to do is replace this message with a field by doing the following:

```
public function fields()
{
    return [
        Text::make('This is a test field')
    ];
}
```

But this is bringing up a text field for the user to fill out. How can I just have text here, without having a user input field please?

Answer (score 2):

According to Laravel Nova [release notes](https://nova.laravel.com/releases/2.5.0), from version 2.5.0 onwards you can customise action modal's confirmation.

Override the `$confirmText` attribute in your Action class.

For example:

```
class YourAction extends Action
{
    /**
     * The text to be used for the action's confirmation text.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $confirmText = 'Your confirmation text?';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @saumini-navaratnam mentioned, you can specify the `$confirmText` in your action. If you want it to be empty, then you would just use the following code:

```
class YourAction extends Action
{
    public $confirmText = null;
}
```

Additionally, you can use a `Heading` field to display html text within your form. Information on this can be found at https://nova.laravel.com/docs/resources/fields.html#heading-field.

```
Heading::make('<p class="text-danger">* All fields are required.</p>')->asHtml(),
```

Nice thing about `Heading` fields is that they are automatically hidden from the resource index page too. I know this doesn't apply to an action, but it comes in handy for resource pages.